# Free function from same namespace in separate .cpp file not recognized in C++

Tags: c++, function, namespaces

I have an auto-generated file1.cpp file with the following format:

```
namespace FirstNS {
namespace SecondNS {
   int newFunction(){
   }
}
}
```

I'm trying to use newFunction within main in a separate mainFile.cpp file. I reference it using
    `FirstNS::SecondNS::newFunction();`

However, I'm getting the following error:

> 'newFunction' is not a member of 'FirstNS::SecondNS'

**Things I've Tried**

- Writing a separate file1.h and including it in the mainFile.cpp. This unfortunately is a problem, because I can't edit the auto-generated file so can't include the header file within file1.cpp
- Including the file1.cpp in the mainFile.cpp. This results the error message "'int newFunction()' is multiply-defined" because it's then imported in multiple files

How do I make it visible/usable to the main of my mainFile.cpp? I can't make any modifications to the generated file1.cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this forward *declaration*

```
namespace FirstNS {
namespace SecondNS {
   int newFunction();
}
}
```

In a header file. Be sure to use `#include` guards, and include that header from `mainFile.cpp`

(You can't multiply *define* a function, which is why you get linking errors when attempting to `#include file1.cpp`).

You might find that the generator tool that you're using can also generate these forward declarations for you.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating another header file?There are many auto-generated files with the same issue, so it would be great if there was a way to include functions without handwriting the headers for all these files

Comment: Presumably the generator tool can't generate the headers then? Do check carefully as that would be the best thing to do.

Comment: Hmm, so I see that it's creating several parentFile.h files which has multiple headers in it, including one for file1.cpp. This parentFile.h is already #included in mainFile.cpp. Is there a reason why it doesn't find them?

Comment: Ah. Now we're getting somewhere. You need to change your compiler's include path so it finds `parentFile.h`. If you don't know how to do that, it's probably best if you ask another question making sure you specify the compiler. Good luck!